# Getting error when using Copy-Item in Simple Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I receive the error message "Illegal Characters in path" when running the following simple script that utilizes the Copy-Item command:

```
$Files = Get-Content output.txt
  ForEach($File in $Files){
     echo $File
     $Directory = Split-Path -Parent $File
     $newDirectory = ($Directory | Out-String) -replace "C:\\test", "C:\Backup"
    echo $newDirectory
    Copy-Item $File $newDirectory -force -recurse
}
```

As you can see the $Files variable is pulling each line into an array.  Each line is actually a file path and name.  The echo outputs look fine and are below:

1. C:\test\testing\text.txt
2. C:\Backup\testing

The first is the orginal file location that is to be copied, the second is the folder to copy it into.  Can anyone help me figure out what the "Illegal character" is in these two paths.  The error points to the source path.

Full Error Code is below:

```
 Copy-Item : Illegal characters in path.
 At C:\users\lane.pulcini\desktop\searchfiles\testcopy.ps1:7 char:10
 + Copy-Item <<<<  $File $newDirectory -force -recurse
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId :       S   System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're receiving.

Comment: Sounds like you have a hidden character somewhere, but we would need the exception unmodified to get a better idea. Have you tried to use `-LiteralPath` as the source-parameter in `Copy-Item`? It usually works better with weird characters. Ex. `Copy-Item -LiteralPath $File -Destination $newdirectory -Force`

Comment: I just edited with the error I am receiving

Comment: I just tried with -LiteralPath and got the same error.

Comment: Does the input file contain any blank lines?

Comment: Is there a "better" format to use within the text document?  Right now it's ANSI.

Comment: No blank lines, that's what I thought is was initially.

Comment: Why are you replacing `\\\`? There should only be one backslash there. Powershell uses the backtick character to escape, not backslash.

Comment: Eris, can you give me an example of what you would use?  I was always taught to escape with '\' with '\\'.

Comment: @Eris - this is because `-replace` operator uses a regex.

Comment: Do any of the lines in the input file have trailing spaces?

Comment: It's connected to the replace line.  If you make that line explicit:   $newDirectory = 'c:\temp'        then it works without error.

Comment: mcr, I took the out-string off and just used $Directory -replace, this allows it to copy, BUT it only copies the files into the root "Backup" directory and doesn't recreate the folder structure... :(

Comment: If your purpose is to replicate subdirectory trees, you can use `robocopy`, which is nicely designed for the task. Type `robocopy /?` for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Out-String` is putting something on the end of the string, so you need to trim it:

```
$newDirectory = (($Directory | Out-String) -replace "C:\\test", "C:\Backup").TrimEnd()
```

...or, remove `Out-String`--I'm not sure why you have it there:

```
$newDirectory = $Directory -replace "C:\\test", "C:\Backup"
```

You can see this by checking the length property:

```
PS C:\> $d = $Directory | out-string
PS C:\> $d.Length
17
PS C:\> $Directory.Length
15
```

If you want the script to create the subfolder under C:\Backup if it doesn't exist, place the following before the `Copy-Item` line:

```
if(!(test-path $newDirectory)){
    New-Item $newDirectory -type directory
}
```

Comment: yeah I took out-string off, which allows it to copy but it's putting it into the root "Backup" folder instead of recreating the folder stucture

Comment: The copy-item command won't create the folder structure.  If the correct specified directory doesn't already exist under c:\Backup, you will need to create it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll use xcopy or robo.

Comment: Yeah, as a general rule of thumb, xcopy and robocopy have a lot of code already written to handle a lot of things nicely, so if they can do the job it is usually just easier to call them.